# Magento soap API forgot password webservice implementation

Tags: magento

Magento soap API forgot password webservice implementation.
I am using Magento soap api for web services. It doesn’t support default forgot password api. Any one can provide me details how can I create the forgot password api and mail send in Magento.

Answer (score 0):

step 1. go to app/etc/modules create a new xml file with your module name (please refer other core xml file for configuration)

step 2. create a directory in app/code/local/ and then name the directory as the module name you created in app/etc/modules

step 3.inside the directory create directory named etc,model,helper and sql if you need to connect to database (then create api.xml,wsdl.xml,config.xml and copy the files from app/code/core/mage/anymodule)